# AMPscript Functions

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

i want to update a custom record in salesforce with html body that is sent to user using AMPscript Fuctions.
Is it possible to update send html body from exact target to salesforce using AMPscript Functions create salesforce record.

update:

i created opportunity look up on Individual Email Results but i am unable to update the opportunity Id on Individual Email Results.

when i add the field in email template using AMPScript Functions the trigger send email is not sending an email instead it getting paused or the sent emails were lost.

**update Feb 17:**
Email are not sent manually as mentioned in the configurations of exact target. so using AMPScript Functions in the email template can i add the html body to update a record in salesforce

**update March 25:**
I am attaching an the email template to salesforce using the click Me option which opens the email in another window.

But when ever i create click on the individual email result record in salesforce it automatically creates on more record.

---

I am attaching an the email template to salesforce using the click Me option which opens the email in another window.

But when ever i create click on the individual email result record in salesforce it automatically creates on more record.

---

i created  opportunity look up on Individual Email Results but  i am unable to update the opportunity Id on Individual Email Results.

when i add the field in email template using AMPScript Functions the trigger send email is not sending an email instead it getting paused or the sent emails were lost.

Email are not sent manually as mentioned in the configurations of exact target.
so using AMPScript Functions in the email template can i add the html body to update a record in salesforce

Comment: Did your question still need an answer?  Are either of the answers below helpful? Be sure to mark the question answered if so, or help us get you the answer you need.

Comment: welcome to salesforce.stackexchange. As has been remarked on your other posts, on stackexchange sites there is a different meaning between answers and comments. Answers are purely intended as answer to your main question (consider them solutions). As they can move up and down based on the votes they get, they are not intended for coversation like in forums. To comment or ask additional information you can use the comment functionality just below questions and answers. Updating your question or answer with additional information (use edit) based on comments received is a positive thing !

Comment: As example, i've taken the liberty to do this for you in this case :).

Answer (score 1):

Yes - this is possible. Currently there is [some configuration that will need done](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-GB/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_for_appexchange/exacttarget_for_appexchange_configuration_guide_for_salesforce_enterprise_and_unlimited_editions/). Once that is complete, you can then use any of the [AMPscript functions listed here](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_salesforcecom/).